# Heat scatter plot with non-numerical output

Tags: r, heatmap, scatter-plot

[Image of excel data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04tDr.png)

I have a table in excel with 100 columns and 100 rows. The column starts at 0% and works up to 100%. Same for the row, starts at 0% and goes up to 100%. It is a 2-way sensitivity analysis, i.e. which drug would be optimal if x(variable in column)=10% and y(variable in row)=30%.

I have 100 by 100 table, with the name of four different drugs scattered across the table. I want to take this data into R and create a scatter plot, essentially a square with 10000 smaller squares. I then want R to colour each square based on the drug which is most optimal for that combination of X and Y.

I've attached an image of dummy data showing the same example in a 10 by 10 table.

Hope you can help!

Comment: please show your code and provide some sample data. Or is it already a problem to load your data into R?

Comment: Hi @wusel, I've added an image to show you what the data looks like on excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start by prepping the data -- reading it in, using something like the `pivot_longer()` function from the `tidyverse` package to make the columns into rows, and then likely doing some clean up on the percentages.

After that, the plot (using `ggplot2`) itself may be pretty straightforward. The `geom_tile()` function is the one that creates the squares.

```
library(tidyverse)
# Create test data
df <- expand_grid(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) %>%
  mutate(drug = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 10000, replace = TRUE))

# Make the plot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = drug)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image: Sample tile output]

Comment: Hi @ravic_ I've uploaded a picture of my problem in the original post to show you what the excel data looks like. I'm not sure what you mean by turning columns into rows. Thanks for replying!

Comment: ERC, reading in the Excel file might require some cleaning, and it's hard to say without you trying some things out. I'd start on that using the `readxl` library, and see what things you'll need to fix.

One thing I think is likely at some point is that instead of a big 100 x 100 square, you'll want to reshape it into a 10000 row sheet. Check out `pivot_longer` in `tidyr`. Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks ravic_ I manage to solve my problem! Used pivot_longer to turn the columns into rows as your suggested and then used geom_title() again as you suggested. Thanks for the tips!! If you know how to remove the annoying edges around the graph that would be much useful